# Stripe customers with attached cards, but no default payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

I am doing a migration for a customer from one platform to another both of which use a Stripe account.

Both platforms only support card payments.
I have noticed, however, that the customers of the existing platform all have a card attached on the Stripe dashboard, but it is not marked as their default payment source. If I retrieve the customers from the API, both their **default_source**, **invoice_settings. default_payment_method** and **sources.data** attributes are **null** or **empty array** respectively.

It doesn't sound likely that I'll be able to charge a customer without a default source. I would like to run some tests on data that looks like the production environment, but no matter how I attach a card to a customer, it automatically gets registered as the customer's default source (if they don't already have another). I have in fact no idea how the previous platform manages to end up in a state where a customer has a card attached on the dashboard, but an empty **sources**-array.

Do any of you know how I can replicate this behaviour using either the API or the dashboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods), such as [attaching a payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/attach), you must set the customer `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` explicitly ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update?lang=node#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method)). With the older [Sources API](https://stripe.com/docs/sources), the `default_source` was set automatically.

If you attached one of the test payment methods, you can recreate the behaviour you describe: you'd have an attached payment method but no defaults set.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Using the payment_methods attach API instead of customer sources to add the card won't mark it as the default source.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rins, did you ever confirm if you were able to charge a customer without a default payment method attached?

Comment: @andrew I'm very sorry, but I don't recall anymore. The migration worked, but I can't remember if I had to change their respective cards to be the default payment method forcibly or not.

Comment: @Andrew probably best to ask another question for what you're trying to do. You can create payments for a customer-attached payment method or a one time use payment method. It's not necessary to set `invoice_settings.default_payment_method` if your use case doesn't need that.

Comment: @Nolan in my case I discovered that although the user didn't have a default payment method, the subscription had saved the payment method and would charge that specifically